# Code does not work on IE9

Tags: javascript, html

Why is the following code working on all browsers except Internet Explorer?

HTML segment:

```
<div class="text" id=“contents”>
  <h2 id=“v1”> </h1>
  <h2 id=“v2”> </h1>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
var t=[], n=2, abp, rtf;

var fun1 = function() {
     t.push((new Date()).getTime());
    if(t.length > n) 
      done();
    else {
      var img = new Image;
      img.onload = fun1;
      img.src=“images/image5.jpg” + "?id=" + (new Date()).getTime();
    }
}


var done = function () {
  rtf =t[2]-t[1];
  abp =t[1]-t[0]-rtf;

  var text1 = rtf;
  var text2 = Math.abs(abp);


   $(‘#v1’).html(text1);
   $(‘#v2’).html(text2);
}

fun1();
```

Comment: What code editor are you using ? How did you get those quotes ?

Comment: It definitely happens upon copying and pasting from other programs @dystroy

Comment: the quotes are not the problem, it copied them like that in this site but in my code they are correct

Comment: The `if else {}` hurts me...

Comment: Is your code's purpose to preload the images.

Answer (score 3):

Those quotes aren't valid :

```
img.src=“images/image5.jpg”

$(‘#v1’)
```

From the specification, [a string literal is defined like this](http://es5.github.io/#x7.8.4) :

```
StringLiteral ::
" DoubleStringCharactersopt "
' SingleStringCharactersopt '
```

---

You have another problem : You use an Image but you immediately liberate it. The browser may cancel the loading as the image isn't attainable in your script anymore.

I would change

```
  var img = new Image;
  img.onload = fun1;
  img.src=“images/image5.jpg” + "?id=" + (new Date()).getTime();
```

to

```
  var img = new Image;
  img.onload = fun1;
  img.src=“images/image5.jpg” + "?id=" + (new Date()).getTime();
  someArray.push(img);
```

with someArray being an array in the global scope.

Comment: "Smart" or curly quotes is what they're called I believe.

Comment: the quotes are not the problem, it copied them like that in this site but in my code they are correct

Answer (score 0):

Replace `"` and  `'`  instead of using `“` and `‘`